# Kivy: how to get rid of the weird shadow look in TextInput?

Tags: kivy, python-3.8, textinput

I've set my TextInput's color to a diffrent one, even though - if you don't click on the TextInput you see a weird shadowed look on the TextInput. Blackish-grey at the top and white on the bottom. How do you get rid of this? I've tried `foreground_color` it doesn't work, even background_color - it doesn't work. How?

Comment: can you provide your code and what the error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `background_normal: ''` to the `TextInput` in your `kv`.